# Find index of numbers from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I would like to get the index of numbers ( 1994 and 27 ) in the string bellow

i tried to split the string but no idea what to do after that

`let str = 'year of birth : 1994 , and i'm 27 yo'`

Comment: hint: `isNan` with JavaScript

Comment: Have a look at Regular Expressions (RegEx).

Comment: @Brad i tried , but thanks i will try again

Comment: @HakimBencella Do you have the code that you tried for regex?  Post it here in your question, we can probably help you debug it pretty easily, and explain it.

Comment: @Brad, it's a project with classes and modules and get data from api , it's not a simple code , but the main idea its to get the response ( string )  from the api and i try to get the index of numbers in the string from the api

Comment: @HakimBencella post the relevant part where you're using regex to match values, no need of posting complete code,

Comment: @CodeManiac , i got the answer thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you split the string. Just loop and check if the value is a number or not.

```
let str = "year of birth : 1994 , and i'm 27 yo";
strArray = str.split(' ');
    for(let i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
        //Use isNaN() to check if the value is a number.
        if(isNaN(strArray[i])==false){
            console.log("Number "+strArray[i]+" is at index "+i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to find index

```
function findindex(str) {
        var num = /\d/;
        var nums = str.match(num);
        return str.indexOf(nums);
    }
```

console.log(findindex('year of birth : 1994'));//will be 16

Answer (score 0):

A convenient fast way is to try [search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).

**The syntax is:**

str.search(regex);

where (**str**) is the string to search in.
(**regex**) is the thing you are searching for.

**The return value**: is the index of the first occurrence of the thing you are after, in your case, a number. From here, it's up to you what to do with this **index**; i.e.: slicing your string starting at this index, maybe??

An important key to use this method is to have enough understanding of the regex industry, which is out of the scope of your question.

Your example:

```js
let str = "year of birth : 1994 , and i'm 27 yo";
let reg = /\d/;
let ind = str.search(reg);
alert('the first instance of "'+reg+'" is found at index: ' + ind);
// expected result is 16, as it is the index of the number (1) in 1994;

//if you want a certain number (not just any number), you
//can modify the reg variable. Let's search for 94, for example..
reg = /94/;
ind = str.search(reg);
alert('the first instance of "'+reg+'" is found at index: ' + ind);
```

Comment: how do u ge tthe length of the occurance

Comment: not sure if I got your qst right? I think you are asking: "how to know how many occurances is there in the string?" If this is the case, then you need to use match(), or matchAll(). Check it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search#description.
But if you want the length of the found string, then you the search() might not be a good help because it doesn't return the captured string you searched for; instead, use match().  YOU NEED TO HAVE enough understanding of the regex realm, specifically the capturing group. check the link above